# Counting Unicode string length without combining marks

Tags: ruby, unicode

Consider the following Ruby code analyzing a three-byte UTF-8 string:

```
#encoding: utf-8
s = "\x65\xCC\x81"
p [s.bytesize, s.length, s, s.encoding.name]
#=> [3, 2, "é", "UTF-8"]
```

As described [on this page of mine](http://phrogz.net/e-acute) the above really *is* a two-character string: Latin lowercase `e` followed by [Combining Acute Accent](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301/index.htm). However, it *looks* like one character, and this matters when laying out fixed-width displays.

*For example, look at the two entries for "moiré.svg" on [this directory listing](http://phrogz.net/svg/) and notice how one of them has messed up the column alignment.*

How can I calculate the 'monospace visual length' of a string in Ruby, which does not include any zero-width combining characters? (One valid technique might be a way to transform a Unicode string into its canonical representation, turning the above into `"\xC3\xA9"` which also looks like `é` but has a `length` of `1`.)

Comment: Which version of Ruby do you have? I tried your example and got `[3, 3, "é"]`.

Comment: @IliaFrenkel The above refers to Ruby 1.9 with an encoding of UTF-8 for strings. I've edited the code to show the magic comment that would be required for a standalone script on any system where UTF-8 is not the default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unicode_utils gem may help

- Current link: https://github.com/lang/unicode_utils
- Old link: http://unicode-utils.rubyforge.org/UnicodeUtils.html

There is a [`char_display_width`](http://unicode-utils.rubyforge.org/UnicodeUtils.html#method-c-char_display_width) method:

```
require "unicode_utils/char_display_width"
UnicodeUtils.char_display_width("別")  # => 2
UnicodeUtils.char_display_width(0x308) # => 0
UnicodeUtils.char_display_width("a")   # => 1
```

There is a string [`display_width`](http://unicode-utils.rubyforge.org/UnicodeUtils.html#method-c-display_width) method:

```
require "unicode_utils/display_width"
UnicodeUtils.display_width("別れ") => 4
UnicodeUtils.display_width("12") => 2
UnicodeUtils.display_width("a\u{308}") => 1
```

Also look at [`each_grapheme`](http://unicode-utils.rubyforge.org/UnicodeUtils.html#method-c-each_grapheme).

(Thanks Michael Anderson for pointing out the additional methods)

Comment: Just found this myself.. But I think counting using the `each_grapheme` method may be more appropriate. http://unicode-utils.rubyforge.org/UnicodeUtils.html#method-c-each_grapheme

Comment: Or better yet. There is a `display_width` that accepts a string rather  than a character.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex to get at the Unicode properties:

```
s = "\x65\xCC\x81"
count = s.each_char.inject(0) do |c, char|
  c += 1 unless char=~/\p{Mn}/
  c
end

puts count #=> 1
```

This works in this case, but you'd have to work out which properties to exclude in a more robust solution.

Using the unicode_utils gem as suggested in [@joelparkerhenderson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10021756/214790) will probably be a better option, but I thought I'd include this for completeness.

Comment: I like this answer for its simplicity and using only core Ruby. Would `s.gsub(/\p{Mn}/,'').length` not work correctly under some circumstance?

Comment: @Phrogz that seems to work, and is more concise than mine. I guess it depends on how things like `gsub` interact with Unicode combining marks, e.g. whether the current behaviour is just an accident or whether it's deliberate, and how it might change in the future. I guess the moral is make sure you've got tests in place.

Answer (score -1):

I am far from being an expert in Ruby but [this](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4527) gives the following:

```
def length_utf8
  count = 0
  scan(/./mu) { count += 1 }
  count
end
```

Comment: This also gives `2` for the string provided by @Phrogz.